# Do you know why my host as router pc is not forwarding packets?

Tags: windows, networking, routing

I want to use my windows 7 pc as a router between 2 interfaces. the goal is providing internet from a modem in interface 2 network to hosts in interface 1 network.

So I've enabled IPEnableRouter in registry and I've started Routing and remote access service.

OK,let's say interface 1 is 192.168.1.10 and interface 2 is 192.168.2.10. And there's a modem router in 192.168.2.1 which has internet connection. Now I want to use my pc which has routing and forwarding enabled as a router to use internet connection in interface 1 network, exactly like my dlink router does.

In my pc(as router) I've set routing table as this:

192.168.1.0/24  ---> 192.168.1.10

192.168.2.0/24  ---> 192.168.2.10

0.0.0.0/0‐---->192.168.2.1

Now for a host in interface 1 network I set gateway to 192.168.1.10 to connect that host to internet. But I can't, in fact the only thing in interface 2 network that I can ping from there is 192.168.2.10, even I can't ping 192.168.2.1 (the modem). What should I do? Maybe a route is missing?

**Please consider this is for learning routing and how it works, so I know there are many ways to accomplish the goal of my question but I want to understand how routing works and what I'm doing wrong here.**

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, a route is missing. It sounds like you haven't told anyone else on subnet 2 that subnet 1 is available via host/router 192.168.2.10, so they're probably sending their ping replies via the modem router at 192.168.2.1, which is probably sending them out the WAN (modem) link.

Comment: Thanks 1.how should I tell them (what's the exact form of route add I need to do, give me an example)

Comment: 2.if it was a host out there with its gateway set at my pc router,then what? Did it need the back route?

Comment: 1. It's hard to give you an exact command without knowing which OS you're dealing with on the other devices. I'm not a Windows guy, but from what I'm seeing online, the general syntax for Windows would be `route add 192.168.1.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 192.168.2.10`.

Comment: 2. If a host on subnet 2 had its **default** gateway set to your PC router, then everything should work fine for that host (it should be pingable from subnet 1, and still have Internet connectivity) because it would be relying on the PC router for all its routing, and currently your PC router is the only device that knows all the relevant routes.

Comment: This is a little beyond the scope of your original question, but if you ultimately want devices on subnet 1 to have Internet connectivity, you'll need your modem router to do NAT for both subnets, and also have a route for subnet 1 via the PC router (192.168.2.10), so that it knows how to route traffic to that subnet.